# Segmentation Fault in pset2 Readability

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on the readability problem in pset 2. I am finding that I get a segmentation fault but I believe I have narrowed down that it is coming from two functions I have created that calculates the number of words and letters in the user inputted text.

```
//function that counts letters
int count_letters(string t)
{
   int letters = 0;

   for (int i = 0, len = strlen(t); i < len; i++)
   {
   if (isalpha(t))
       {
       letters++;
       }
   }
return letters;

}

//function that counts words
int count_words(string t)
{
   int words = 1;

   for (int x = 0, len = strlen(t); x < len; x++)
   {
       if (isspace(t))
       {
           words++;
       }
   }
return words;
}
```

I am unsure how to fix the issue and would be open to any advice.

P.S. Sorry for any formating issues this is my first time posting to stack overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; t[i]; i++)` (adjust `x` loop accordingly)

Comment: Follow David's fix and then do: `if (isspace((unsigned char) t[i]))`

Answer (score 0):

First, please describe what you're talking about. It's not at all clear what the "readability problem in pset 2" is. Googling gave me some idea, but we shouldn't have to do that.
Second, isalpha() and isspace() take a char, not a string. You probably want

> if (isalpha(t[i]))

Plus, you currently don't even use the variable 'i'. You should also check if 't' is a NULL string or not before dereferencing it. That's the most common cause of segfaults.
Third, the count_words() routine will always return at least 1. What if the passed in string is empty or only whitespace?